# Unrecognized Selector Instance When Performing Segue

Tags: ios, swift

When performing programatically performing a segue, the segue does work and the intended storyboard opens, but terminates immediately afterwards. The view controller/storyboard does work and shouldn't have any errors in the code as I've tested it individually, so I'm not entirely sure as to why it terminates. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    2017-05-01 20:22:59.358605 FInal Project[15659:499662] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/student/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/265EA47F-07A6-47C7-A6B4-5E62D37E72BA/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-01 20:22:59.376075 FInal Project[15659:499662] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
in 
2017-05-01 20:23:48.095 FInal Project[15659:499662] <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fdae3c082f0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000242be0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000003ea40>>'s window is not equal to <UINavigationController: 0x7fdae40aee00>'s view's window!
2017-05-01 20:23:48.715 FInal Project[15659:499662] -[FInal_Project.User_Info NameInputEditingDidEnd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdae3c11d40
2017-05-01 20:23:48.721 FInal Project[15659:499662] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FInal_Project.User_Info NameInputEditingDidEnd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdae3c11d40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fc3d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101a2521e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102033f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f49005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f48b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001030cb8bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103251c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103251f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103bdbc20 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 313
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001032e1778 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 286
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103bdba0e -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 49
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001032e1827 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000103bdb8dd -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 136
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010317802f -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 167
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001031786b8 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 76
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010317846a -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 95
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010324d451 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke.629 + 704
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000103246fba -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 111
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010345ef83 -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 42
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010324aef0 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000103c0c56c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 102
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000103243ddc -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 251
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103243aef -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1539
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010324651c -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000103156bd5 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 222
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010315712a -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 136
    26  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108526648 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 316
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105e2e0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105e0e8a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f87e49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f4d37d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f4c884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107d38a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    33  UIKit                               0x00000001030c9c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    34  FInal Project                       0x00000001013fb65f main + 111
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105e7a68d start + 1
    36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do you have an action in the storyboard called `NameInputEditingDidEnd` that is not hooked up to an action in code?

Comment: I don't have an action called NameInputEditingDidEnd. It was there at one point but it was deleted a few days ago

Comment: Exactly! If you check the outlets tab in the storyboard and click around a bit, you'll probably find an outlet to something called `NameInputEditingDidEnd`. What's happening is the storyboard is looking for a selector, which it can't find in the code, so it crashes. Check on your view controller for `User_Info`.

Comment: Looking around, there are no actions under Editing Did End or anything by that name. I might be looking in the wrong place? (I'm new to xcode so I'm still figuring things out)

Comment: Found it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Open the storyboard file as source code (right-click on the file in Xcode then Open As -> Source Code) and do a text search for `NameInputEditingDidEnd`

Comment: @R.R Great! I summarized the solution in an answer below to make it easier for future readers to find.

Answer (score 1):

The issue (discovered in the comments above) was that there was an action in the storyboard that was no longer hooked up to an action in code.

If anyone else in the future has a similar problem, look through the outlets menu for an outlet or action with the name provided in the console output. In this case, the action was named `NameInputEditingDidEnd`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Nathan's answer, instead of randomly looking around, just cmd+shift+f the name of the outlet, in this case `NameInputEditingDidEnd`, and xcode will output the storyboard with the dangling outlet for you and center you to it.

[image: Like so]